# How do you host a multi-player survival game in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've downloaded all the required files in order to host an on-line multi-player Minecraft game on my computer, and successfully made a server. However, it seems that I can only make games in free build mode, where you have unlimited resources to build with. I prefer the survival mode where you have limited hp, there's a day/night cycle, mobs spawn, etc (the registered user version, not the classic free version).

Is it possible to host a survival multi-player game, whether on-line or local?

EDIT: Given Minecraft is undergoing huge changes please update your answers as appropriate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to download the multiplayer survival server. It can be found at https://minecraft.net/download at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Whoops, I downloaded one on this page originally (http://www.minecraft.net/servers.jsp), do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: The one that WedTm posted is known as the SMP (Survival MultiPlayer) server.  It enables some of the features in single player.  However there are several features missing, such as inventory retention and combat.

Comment: For the sake of completion, Inventory Retention is enabled, and combat is half there (You can fight and there's mobs but nobody takes or does damage)

Comment: @Alex:  Well, you can do damage to mobs using fire/lava/pushing them off cliffs, and even obtain their special items (silk gunpowder etc.)

Answer (score 5):

You can now host a local multiplayer server without any additional software.

Start or continue your map in Single Player, press <kbd>esc</kbd> and select

"Open to Lan".

[image]

Other players can then join your game from the Multiplayer menu. The LAN game should be automatically detected.

Comment: This question was made way before the `Open to LAN` feature came out though, and I don't think that's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @JeffreyLin This answer was not for the benefit of OP directly but for future visitors. This is the new standard, even if it wasn't when the question was asked.

Comment: I do agree with you, but you should note in your answer that only people using the same WiFi network can see your server, and that you will not be able to install mods or things like that.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is only a __local__ server, which might not be what the asker of the question wants.