# How can I play multiplayer against creeps on Minecraft SMP servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I purchased Minecraft yesterday and from what I've read, I understand that there are survival multiplayer servers, but so far none have any survival elements. Most have day/night cycles, but you can't lose health and no creeps spawn.

How can I play multiplayer against creeps?

**Update:** I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/how-do-you-host-a-multi-player-survival-game-in-minecraft) on how to host a SMP game.

Comment: Part of your question details may be good as the title, so it's actually a question. I had no idea what to expect when I clicked it. Perhaps 'Can I play Minecraft multiplayer with survival elements?' or something.

Comment: Fixed question title.

Comment: Ah, I remember way back when, before all these things were added. I like to think of them as the "good old days", "my day", "when I was a boy". Good times, good times :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A further update: As of Minecraft Release 1.0 (as in, after Alpha and after Beta), SMP offers everything single-player does, including Survival mode, Creative mode, and the Nether and End regions. There are still glitches that only affect SMP, meaning certain animations and so forth might not play properly, but the game is no longer woefully incomplete in SMP.

As of **Release 1.3.1**, SMP and SSP are now using identical code. Single-player is now a one-person instance of multiplayer. Thus, all differences between the two have been reconciled.

Comment: Most of the glitches are thankfully graphical (spawners always show pigs), except for the drowning knockback bug still present in 1.1, which knocks you *downwards*.

Comment: @Broam You're not supposed to sink further when drowning? >.> I should admit, most of my playtime is on SMP, because I host a little server to play with my friends and family, so even when playing alone I generally log into the server. So I've never seen spawners with mobs inside the cage or the jump animation for nether-slimes or so on.

Comment: Start a single-player world & go swimming; you'll see you can easily surface while drowning.

Answer (score 11):

Add `monsters=true` (or `spawn-monsters=true`) to your server.properties file, and monsters will spawn.  This is the default setting on minecraft servers; set them to `=false` instead for **no** monsters.

Comment: sadly, it was not fixed in the Halloween update :(

Comment: This answer is completely outdated, I fear. Please update it.

Comment: @Bobby - fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Such things are currently not supported.  The game is still in Alpha, which means there are still features to be built and that it is not to be taken as a reliable polished game.

Luckily, there is a rather large update coming October 31st.  Here is Notch's blog describing what you can expect from it: http://notch.tumblr.com/post/1243370641

So, for now, Survival Multi Player is more of a sandboxy free-building mode and less of an actual Survival experience, but as the game continues to be developed, SMP will come into its own.

**Edit: Clearly this answer is completely outdated.**

Comment: Cool, can't wait for creeps :).

Comment: new patches often bring new bugs, especially if I look at the former Minecraft devlopement....

Answer (score 2):

Just as an update, with the exception of the Nether the SMP server providers everything SSP offers, including Creepers and the ability to kill them. (Yeah, that way around sounds better... Sssss....)

Comment: The last time I signed into a local SMP server there were creeps, but there was so much lag that one second a spider was over there - the next second you were dead. Has the lag issues been addressed?

Comment: @FreshCode I don't know, I only played on LAN and didn't experience any lag there...