# How do you make NPC's in multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm an OP on my friends' server and I'm wondering how to make NPCs. Apparently no mods are required.

Comment: @fail badp: it has even gooderer!

Comment: @Stuart Embetterenedly.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/how-can-i-play-multiplayer-against-creeps-on-minecraft-smp-servers/8919#8919

Comment: related: [How to play Minecolony in SMP?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-play-minecolony-in-smp)

Answer (score 13):

You are unable to add NPCs to a server without adding mods. However, some popular Bukkit plugins that allow you to add NPCs include:

### [npcx](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/fun-npcx-0-165-556-everquest-style-bots-paths-aggro-loot-guard-shops-quest-chat.9186/)

[image: Yay, picture!]

> Implements everquest style npc spawngroups using the npc library allowing you to make persistent npcs/rare npcs spawn around your map. Npcs will fight back if attacked and even talk on right click. They will sell items and can even have loot assigned and be given factions and paths to walk

---

### [NpcSpirit](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-npcspirit-v1-11-block-based-npc-system-now-sqlite-persistent-cb493.7331/)

> The point of NpcSpirit is to create an Npc system that will tie in well with world economies and player constructed environments, rather than having them be an administrated constant. A certain kind of block (sponge by default but editable in config) is denoted as containing the souls of NPCs. When this is placed, it spawns an npc and will continue to do so when the npc is killed. Admins or the Npc's owner may change the npc's name(and associated skin pulled from minecraft.net), equipped item, greetings, threats and conversation.

---

### [Citizens](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/mech-citizens-v1-06-npcs-for-bukkit-traders-guards-quests-coming-soon-556.7173/)

> Citizens is an NPC plugin in the vein of the old hey0 ones, aimed at creating NPCs that perform a variety of tasks, such as dispensing information. Currently NPCs can be created and say a set line once rightclicked with a specified item, however, more features will be added soon, such as traders and more. Citizens supports Permissions but will default to ops only if not available.

Comment: i've found out about it

Comment: Where is the link for download?

Comment: @MikeXable The title of each mod is linked to its respective Bukkit thread, where you can find download links for them and install them on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean make them spawn?

This can only be done in the server configuration file by setting one or both of:

```
spawn-monsters=true
spawn-animals=true
```

and restarting the server.

Comment: I think anakinkp means NPCs, as in other characters you can interact with (like other players) - not mobs.

Comment: @Kevin NPCs are non-player characters though, like monsters and animals. There are no AI controlled characters in minecraft.

Comment: there are, however, ways to create dummy players - I've seen these used as handy "teleport" targets.

Comment: @Kevin if that is the case then I want to know how to do that too!

Answer (score -2):

```
/npc create [namegoeshere]
```

They also imitate your skin — if I would make one named AndTuts, it will have my skin.

Comment: There's no `/npc` command. You're talking about a custom server software or plug-in of some description, and unless you mention what it is as well, your answer is of no use to anyone.